# Passing Data from Parent to Child when Calling an API in Angular Node.js

Tags: angular

I am using Angular for my frontend and Node.js as the backend. I am trying to get data from an API and show it using angular. I have a search-home component wehre my search bar is, and I have a search-results component as the child of the search-home. when I submit the form, the data is fetched by the parent, but it is not able to pass it properly to the child:

here is my search-home component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppServiceService } from '../app-service.service';
import { SearchResultsComponent } from './search-results/search-results.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-home',
  templateUrl: './search-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-home.component.css']
})
export class SearchHomeComponent {


  responseData: any;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: AppServiceService) {

  }
  
  

  searchTicker(searchInputValue: string) {

    
    
    this.service.getData(searchInputValue).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.responseData = response;
        console.log('ResponseData property is:', this.responseData);
        this.router.navigate(['/search', searchInputValue]);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error is', error);
      }
    );
   
  }
}
```

```html
<p>search-home works!</p>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div >
    stock search
</div>
<form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="searchTicker(searchInput.value)" #form="ngForm">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input #searchInput class="form-control  border rounded-pill" type="search" placeholder="Enter Stock Ticker Symbol">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary border rounded-pill ms-n5" type="submit">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
</form>

<app-search-results [myresponseData]="responseData"></app-search-results>
```

this is my search-results component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from 'stream';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-results',
  templateUrl: './search-results.component.html',
  styleUrl: './search-results.component.css'
})
export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnChanges{



  @Input() myresponseData: any;


  //by the time the constructor gets called, the myresponseData will not be updated with the value passed from parent component(output is undefined)
  constructor(){
    console.log("search-results constructor called");
    console.log('property of constructor', this.myresponseData);
  }
 
  //at some point the property will be updated with the value from parent component, and the ngOnChanges lifecylce hook will be called
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log('ngonchanges lifecycle hook called');
    console.log('changes that are made', changes);
  }
}
```

```
<p>search-results works!</p>
<div *ngIf="myresponseData">
    <h2>Data from API:</h2>
    <pre>{{ myresponseData | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

The weird thing is that the first time I submit the form nothing is shown, but the second time it does.

I would appreciate any help!

As you can see, I tried using ngOnChanges to trakc the change in child component property. The first time I submit the form, both the previous and current value are undefined, and they only change the second time I submit :)

Comment: I wonder if the router navigation is causing a problem.  Does it work if you comment that line out?

Comment: The problem was that I had an extra routing path (two routes were going to the same path

`const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'search/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  //{path:'search/home', component: SearchHomeComponent},
  {path:'search/:ticker', component: SearchHomeComponent},
  {path:'watchlist', component: WatchlistComponent},
  {path:'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent}
];`

and commenting the unnecessary one solved this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Negar please add your comment as an answer and accept your answer, so everyone can see that this is solved

Answer (score 0):

The problem was is not with the data binding but the way I have defined my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [   
{path: '', redirectTo: 'search/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
//{path:'search/home', component: SearchHomeComponent},   
{path:'search/:ticker', component: SearchHomeComponent},  
{path:'watchlist', component: WatchlistComponent},   
{path:'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent} ];
```

and commenting out the unnecessary one solves this issue.